# How to prevent font change on mobile (android) version of site

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, fonts

I use Futura as the default font for my web app:

```
body {
    font-family:Futura, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Ever since I added

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
```

for mobile formatting, the font has changed to a thin sans-serif font (that doesn't look like verdana) on my Android device. (However, the font has remained the same for iOS.)

How can I ensure that the font stays Futura/choose a specific font for the mobile version of the site?

Comment: Are you sure the `meta` tag caused it? Does the Android device you use for testing have Futura or Verdana installed, or are you simply seeing the text in the default sans-serif font of the device?

Answer (score 0):

if font is not available on device it will change it to next and next. try to use Google font its safe. though I don't love google font since its not sharp enough on mobile devices specially

Answer (score 0):

you can add any of the font (same use as website) apply in your mobile application.you  can use ttf file to set font of mobile application easy.

I hope its useful to you.